# PutHDFS processor fails to write to kerberised and TLS/SSL enabled HDFS

Tags: hdfs, apache-nifi, put

I get the below error message in my NiFi logs when I tried to write a file to HDFS, but when i try to write a file with in the hadoop cluster it works fine, but from NiFi it fails with the below message.

```
2020-08-10 13:41:59,519 INFO [NiFi Web Server-32056] o.a.n.c.s.StandardProcessScheduler Starting LogMessage[id=b4bc6d2c-0173-1000-0000-00002905a41b]


2020-08-10 13:41:59,519 INFO [NiFi Web Server-32056] o.a.n.controller.StandardProcessorNode Starting LogMessage[id=b4bc6d2c-0173-1000-0000-00002905a41b]
2020-08-10 13:41:59,519 INFO [NiFi Web Server-32056] o.a.n.c.s.StandardProcessScheduler Starting LogMessage[id=b4bd264b-0173-1000-0000-000018f91304]
2020-08-10 13:41:59,519 INFO [NiFi Web Server-32056] o.a.n.controller.StandardProcessorNode Starting LogMessage[id=b4bd264b-0173-1000-0000-000018f91304]
2020-08-10 13:41:59,519 INFO [NiFi Web Server-32056] o.a.n.c.s.StandardProcessScheduler Starting GetFile[id=b4d14ae8-0173-1000-ffff-ffffe680a6a0]
2020-08-10 13:41:59,519 INFO [NiFi Web Server-32056] o.a.n.controller.StandardProcessorNode Starting GetFile[id=b4d14ae8-0173-1000-ffff-ffffe680a6a0]
2020-08-10 13:41:59,519 INFO [NiFi Web Server-32056] o.a.n.c.s.StandardProcessScheduler Starting PutHDFS[id=4d34342b-2901-125d-917f-567e466964c8]
2020-08-10 13:41:59,519 INFO [NiFi Web Server-32056] o.a.n.controller.StandardProcessorNode Starting PutHDFS[id=4d34342b-2901-125d-917f-567e466964c8]
2020-08-10 13:41:59,519 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Scheduled GetFile[id=b4d14ae8-0173-1000-ffff-ffffe680a6a0] to run with 1 threads
2020-08-10 13:41:59,519 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Scheduled LogMessage[id=b4bc6d2c-0173-1000-0000-00002905a41b] to run with 1 threads
2020-08-10 13:41:59,519 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Scheduled LogMessage[id=b4bd264b-0173-1000-0000-000018f91304] to run with 1 threads
2020-08-10 13:41:59,543 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] o.a.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation Login successful for user abc@UX.xyzCORP.NET using keytab file /home/abc/confFiles/abc.keytab
2020-08-10 13:41:59,544 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Scheduled PutHDFS[id=4d34342b-2901-125d-917f-567e466964c8] to run with 1 threads
2020-08-10 13:41:59,595 INFO [Thread-9481] o.a.h.h.p.d.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-08-10 13:41:59,599 INFO [Thread-9481] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer Exception in createBlockOutputStream blk_1075334640_1594409
java.io.EOFException: null
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readVLong(WritableUtils.java:308)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readVInt(WritableUtils.java:329)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.security.token.block.BlockTokenIdentifier.readFieldsLegacy(BlockTokenIdentifier.java:240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.security.token.block.BlockTokenIdentifier.readFields(BlockTokenIdentifier.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.Token.decodeIdentifier(Token.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.doSaslHandshake(SaslDataTransferClient.java:530)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.getEncryptedStreams(SaslDataTransferClient.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.send(SaslDataTransferClient.java:276)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.checkTrustAndSend(SaslDataTransferClient.java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.socketSend(SaslDataTransferClient.java:203)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.socketSend(SaslDataTransferClient.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1731)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1679)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:716)
2020-08-10 13:41:59,599 WARN [Thread-9481] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer Abandoning BP-1824237254-0.00.64.55-1545405130172:blk_1075334640_1594409
2020-08-10 13:41:59,601 WARN [Thread-9481] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[0.00.64.57:50010,DS-d6f56418-6e18-4317-a8ec-4a5b15757728,DISK]
2020-08-10 13:41:59,605 INFO [Thread-9481] o.a.h.h.p.d.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-08-10 13:41:59,606 INFO [Thread-9481] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer Exception in createBlockOutputStream blk_1075334641_1594410
java.io.EOFException: null
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readVLong(WritableUtils.java:308)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readVInt(WritableUtils.java:329)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.security.token.block.BlockTokenIdentifier.readFieldsLegacy(BlockTokenIdentifier.java:240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.security.token.block.BlockTokenIdentifier.readFields(BlockTokenIdentifier.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.Token.decodeIdentifier(Token.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.doSaslHandshake(SaslDataTransferClient.java:530)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.getEncryptedStreams(SaslDataTransferClient.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.send(SaslDataTransferClient.java:276)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.checkTrustAndSend(SaslDataTransferClient.java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.socketSend(SaslDataTransferClient.java:203)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.socketSend(SaslDataTransferClient.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1731)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1679)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:716)
2020-08-10 13:41:59,606 WARN [Thread-9481] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer Abandoning BP-1824237254-0.00.64.55-1545405130172:blk_1075334641_1594410
2020-08-10 13:41:59,608 WARN [Thread-9481] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[0.00.64.56:50010,DS-286b28e8-d035-4b8c-a2dd-aabb08666234,DISK]
2020-08-10 13:41:59,612 INFO [Thread-9481] o.a.h.h.p.d.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-08-10 13:41:59,612 INFO [Thread-9481] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer Exception in createBlockOutputStream blk_1075334642_1594411
java.io.EOFException: null
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readVLong(WritableUtils.java:308)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readVInt(WritableUtils.java:329)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.security.token.block.BlockTokenIdentifier.readFieldsLegacy(BlockTokenIdentifier.java:240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.security.token.block.BlockTokenIdentifier.readFields(BlockTokenIdentifier.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.Token.decodeIdentifier(Token.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.doSaslHandshake(SaslDataTransferClient.java:530)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.getEncryptedStreams(SaslDataTransferClient.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.send(SaslDataTransferClient.java:276)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.checkTrustAndSend(SaslDataTransferClient.java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.socketSend(SaslDataTransferClient.java:203)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.socketSend(SaslDataTransferClient.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1731)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1679)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:716)
2020-08-10 13:41:59,612 WARN [Thread-9481] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer Abandoning BP-1824237254-0.00.64.55-1545405130172:blk_1075334642_1594411
2020-08-10 13:41:59,614 WARN [Thread-9481] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[0.00.64.58:50010,DS-53536364-33f4-40d6-85c2-508abf7ff023,DISK]
2020-08-10 13:41:59,618 INFO [Thread-9481] o.a.h.h.p.d.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-08-10 13:41:59,619 INFO [Thread-9481] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer Exception in createBlockOutputStream blk_1075334643_1594412
java.io.EOFException: null
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readVLong(WritableUtils.java:308)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readVInt(WritableUtils.java:329)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.security.token.block.BlockTokenIdentifier.readFieldsLegacy(BlockTokenIdentifier.java:240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.security.token.block.BlockTokenIdentifier.readFields(BlockTokenIdentifier.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.Token.decodeIdentifier(Token.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.doSaslHandshake(SaslDataTransferClient.java:530)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.getEncryptedStreams(SaslDataTransferClient.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.send(SaslDataTransferClient.java:276)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.checkTrustAndSend(SaslDataTransferClient.java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.socketSend(SaslDataTransferClient.java:203)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.socketSend(SaslDataTransferClient.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1731)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1679)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:716)
2020-08-10 13:41:59,619 WARN [Thread-9481] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer Abandoning BP-1824237254-0.00.64.55-1545405130172:blk_1075334643_1594412
2020-08-10 13:41:59,621 WARN [Thread-9481] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[0.00.64.84:50010,DS-abba7d97-925a-4299-af86-b58fef9aaa12,DISK]
2020-08-10 13:41:59,621 WARN [Thread-9481] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer DataStreamer Exception
java.io.IOException: Unable to create new block.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1694)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:716)
*2020-08-10 13:41:59,621 WARN [Thread-9481] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer Could not get block locations. Source file "/user/abc/puthdfs_test/.test.txt" - Aborting...block==null*
2020-08-10 13:41:59,626 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.PutHDFS PutHDFS[id=4d34342b-2901-125d-917f-567e466964c8] Failed to write to HDFS due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: IOException thrown from PutHDFS[id=4d34342b-2901-125d-917f-567e466964c8]: java.io.IOException: Could not get block locations. Source file "/user/abc/puthdfs_test/.test.txt" - Aborting...block==null: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: IOException thrown from PutHDFS[id=4d34342b-2901-125d-917f-567e466964c8]: java.io.IOException: Could not get block locations. Source file "/user/abc/puthdfs_test/.test.txt" - Aborting...block==null
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: IOException thrown from PutHDFS[id=4d34342b-2901-125d-917f-567e466964c8]: java.io.IOException: Could not get block locations. Source file "/user/abc/puthdfs_test/.test.txt" - Aborting...block==null
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, i have eliminated that it has nothing to do with HDFS

Thanks
David

Comment: kerberos credentials you have provided in the NiFi processor?

Comment: Yes, I have created a kerberos credentials service and added that to the NiFi PutHDFS processor, I am using PutSQL processor using the same keberos crendentials i am able to insert data into hive and that works fine.

Comment: `2020-08-10 13:41:59,543 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] o.a.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation Login successful for user abc@UX.xyzCORP.NET using keytab file /home/abc/confFiles/abc.keytab` I could see this INFO state that login is successful. I think the error is due to someother issue.

Comment: `hadoop dfsadmin -report` could you share the output of this command and check whether datanodes are up & running. (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/EOFException)

Comment: [hdfssuperuser@abc ~]$ hadoop dfsadmin -report


Configured Capacity: 8748844187648 (7.96 TB)
Present Capacity: 8649609633023 (7.87 TB)
DFS Remaining: 6585870316863 (5.99 TB)
DFS Used: 2063739316160 (1.88 TB)
DFS Used%: 23.86%

Live datanodes (4):

Name: 0.1.0.1:50010 
Hostname: abc
Rack: /default
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 2187211046912 (1.99 TB)
DFS Used: 673284505773 (627.05 GB)
Non DFS Used: 24917778259 (23.21 GB)
DFS Remaining: 1488606111329 (1.35 TB)
DFS Used%: 30.78%
DFS Remaining%: 68.06%

Comment: There are 4 datanodes and all are up and running

Comment: resolution for this issue is to downgrade from NiFi 1.11.4 to 1.11.3 as there is a bug while writing files to HDFS using NiFi 1.11.4 to Cloudera or Hadoop clusters which run on Hadoop 2.x version. here is the jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-15191